# Possible to get 100Hz with HDMI to DP adapter?

Tags: display, hdmi, cable, displayport, adapter

I have this laptop from Lenovo: https://www.lenovo.com/lt/lt/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Legion-Y520/p/88GMY500808

And bought this monitor from Acer: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/predator-model/UM.CZ1AA.P01

If I understood it correctly, I can't get those sweet 100Hz with HDMI cable, but my laptop does not have any DP port.

Would it be possible to have 100Hz with some kind of adapter? USB-c to DP would also be fine for me. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: No adapter can do that.

Comment: How about USB-C? Basically I'm stuck with this laptop?

Comment: Usually a higher refresh rate requires the usage of NVIDIA® G-SYNC or AMD FreeSync. Your monitor only supports NVidia G-Sync. Tech spec of your notebook does not mention G-sync at all, therefore most likely it is neither supported for the internal monitor nor the external hdmi port.

Comment: As above, and the USB-C port may not even work for video (not mentioned in the specifications)